# Swift/Regex: How can I format a string using stringByReplacingMatches(withTemplate)?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to format a numeric string, for example `123456789`, so the first digit would be separated, then every 2 digits would be grouped, to get this result:

> 1 23 45 67 89

I have tried this:

```
let givenText = "123456789"
let text = (try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([0-9])([0-9])(?!$)",
                                     options: .caseInsensitive))?
.stringByReplacingMatches(in: givenText,
                          options: .reportProgress,
                          range: NSMakeRange(0, givenText.count),
                          withTemplate: "$0 ")
```

But I'm getting this result instead:

> 12 34 56 78 9

I have no idea how I can isolate the first digit. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your "text" always going to be a number? You could do this with `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to change your regular expression to match one number at the start of the string or two numbers.

```
((^[0-9])|([0-9]{2}))(?!$)
```

Comment: I love seeing ingenious stuff like this :-) You could replace `[0-9]` with `\d` to save some chars.